# I am getting an error regarding the use of the function float, how do I solve it?

Tags: postgresql, bigdata, pentaho, dbeaver

I am trying to convert what is inside the parenthesis into a float type but I keep getting the same error.

I have already tried to change the parenthesis in order to envelop the whole expression in float before convert but it still gives me the same error. Please le tme know what could I do in order to avoid this error.

```
SELECT     
    inter.IDIntervento, 'Intervento principale' as _IDInterventoTipo, 1 as _IDInterventoTipoN,
    inter.IDIntervento as _IDInterventoRif, inter.IDInterventoV, 
    IDCartella, IDCdc, IDCdc|| IDCartella as IDCdcIDCartella,
    ECO.TipoCardio,
    ECO.DataEsame,
    ECO.Operatore,
    ECO.TipoEco, 
    convert(float,replace(ECO.DiametroTelediastolicoVentricoloSinistro,',','.')) as VentricoloSinistro_DiametroTelediastolico,
    convert(float,replace(ECO.VolumeTelediastolicoVentricoloSinistro,',','.')) as VentricoloSinistro_VolumeTelediastolico,
    convert(float,replace(ECO.DiametroTelediastolico2VentricoloSinistro,',','.')) as VentricoloSinistro_DiametroTelediastolico2,
    convert(float,replace(ECO.VolumeTelediastolico2VentricoloSinistro,',','.')) as VentricoloSinistro_VolumeTelediastolico2,
    (SELECT cast(idinterventovalore as varchar(5))|| '='|| valore  
    FROM cch.pats_cch_interventi_valori val
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the error tells me that the column float does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `convert` converts strings from one encoding to another.

To convert a string to a floating point number, use a type cast:

```
CAST (replace(ECO.DiametroTelediastolicoVentricoloSinistro,',','.')
      AS double precision) AS VentricoloSinistro_DiametroTelediastolico
```

Comment: I get it, but if I use cast instead of convert the replace function does not work anymore.

Comment: I have edited the answer to show how it would be used in your example.